# How can cumulative delta for options over an interval be calculated?

Tags: options, delta

How can a graph like on the bottom of the image be created? What information is needed?

([image])

Comment: I suspect it is not Delta in the Black Scholes sense, but rather a measure of volume of trades at the ask minus volume of trades at the bid. So it is derived from transactions and quotes data, just like the top table showing unusual (i.e. big) transactions. In the top table SELL means trade at the bid, BUY means trade at the ask, MIDDLE means within bid and ask. BUYS raise Delta, SELLS lower it.

Comment: (the second row of the top table, a big buy of puts at the ask at 10:31:40, contributes to  the orange line in the graph rising after 10:30 am)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation